# ImportError: cannot import name 'TryExcept' from 'utils' (mypath/utils.py)

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-import, yolov5

I have a script with the following folder structure:

```
myfolder/
    myscript.py
    utils.py
    mymodels/
        mymodel.py
        utils.py
```

within the `myscript.py` I call:

```
from utils import funca, funcb, funcc
from mymodel.utils import DataLoader
from mymodels.mymodel import *
```

But mymodel itself import loads a yolov5 Modell from `torch.hub` and throws the following error message:

```
  File "/home/vitouser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/hub.py", line 540, in load
    model = _load_local(repo_or_dir, model, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vitouser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/hub.py", line 569, in _load_local
    model = entry(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vitouser/.cache/torch/hub/ultralytics_yolov5_master/hubconf.py", line 83, in custom
    return _create(path, autoshape=autoshape, verbose=_verbose, device=device)
  File "/home/vitouser/.cache/torch/hub/ultralytics_yolov5_master/hubconf.py", line 33, in _create
    from models.common import AutoShape, DetectMultiBackend
  File "/home/vitouser/.cache/torch/hub/ultralytics_yolov5_master/models/common.py", line 28, in <module>
    from utils import TryExcept
ImportError: cannot import name 'TryExcept' from 'utils' (/myfolder/utils.py)
```

I am guessing the extensive use of `"utils"` is causing some form of issue. Since Python cant find the `TryExcept` in my own `/myfolder/utils.py`.
How do I get rid of this problem.
Just calling my `mymodel.py` file from the shell using python does not cause any issues. So I am guessing it must be the import of the my utils file.